# How to automatically populate a value in Map < String, Collection > on demand

Tags: java, collections

I find myself often writing such code:

```
Map < String, Set < String > > map = new TreeMap < String, Set < String > >();
String key;
String element;
/* ... */
Set < String > value = map.get(key);
if (value == null) {
  value = new TreeSet < String >();
  map.put(key, value);
}
value.add(element);
```

I hate the `if` statement above -- how can I get rid of it in standard Java?  If you can confirm that there is no standard Java solution, it would then be nice if you could suggest a non-standard library that addresses this need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Commons Collections has a [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html):

```
MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
mhm.put(key, "A");
mhm.put(key, "B");
mhm.put(key, "C");
Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get(key);
```

Guava (used to be Google Collections) [has one too](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), which supports generics, and has both a [tree](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) and [hash](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html) version:

```
Multimap<String,String> mhm = new TreeMultimap<String,String>();
// etc.
```

To clarify, `Multimap<T, S>` is basically the same as a `Map<T, Collection<S>>`, and `put` automatically creates the collection if it needs to.

EDIT: Updated to link to Guava, since apparently Google Collections is deprecated.

Comment: Please don't link to the google-collections project; as it says on its home page, it is long-deprecated. It's equivalent to Guava 0.0 and we are currently releasing Guava 12.0.

Comment: @KevinBourrillion - Since you work for Google, I think it's fair for me to complain that I just did [a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+multimap) and took the top results ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I like Brendan's multimap answer, but you could also use a static utility method and keep to standard java.util classes/interfaces:

```
public static <K,V> Set<V> getTreeSet(Map<K,Set<V>> map, K key) {
    Set<V> set = map.get(key);
    if (set == null) {
        set = new TreeSet<V>();
        map.put(key, set);
    }
    return set;
}
```

Then your code with the null checks could be written:

```
Map < String, Set < String > > map = new TreeMap < String, Set < String > >();
String key;
String element;
/* ... */
MapUtils.getTreeSet(map, key).add(element);
```

You'd need static method for each collection type, but that seems better than writing the same code over and over again.

Comment: Thanks - I used to maintain a similar piece of code but I'm fed up of tracking it and including it in every project and so I am looking for something standard. It seems like there's nothing standard and in that case it is probably easy to just plug in Guava rather than maintain my own code. (Guava is available in standard maven repositories so it is super-easy to integrate and build wherever.)

Comment: Yup, I use Guava all the time.  It would be nice if they included something like this in their Maps class, seeing how Multimaps have slightly different semantics than `Map<K,Set<V>>`.

Comment: what's the slight difference?

Comment: Little things like `SetMultimap<K,V>.entries()` returns an `Set<Entry<K,V>>`, whereas `Map<K,Set<V>>.entrySet()` returns a `Set<Entry<K,Set<V>>>` -- so iterating over all entries is different.  But you can get around most of these differences by using `SetMultimap.asMap()` method.

Comment: nice observation: i like having `Set<Entry<K,V>>` with the fallback option of `Set<Entry<K,Set<V>>>`. i hope they move this into the standard java library where they have already done some good work with things like `NavigableMap`